# Is there an official English version of LTF-UL?

Tags: regulations, ultralight, germany

I have found the German version of the ultralight regulations under Germany airworthiness authority, but I have not found a link for English version of that. is there any?

Comment: I had translated it all in 2019, while working on the "certification" of an ultralight. I can see if I find the files next week (first week of March).

Answer (score 1):

For [LTF-UL 2019](https://web.archive.org/web/20201207004018/https://www.daec.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/2019/Luftsportgeraete_Buero/LTF/LTF-UL_2019.pdf) there is no official English translation, unlike, say, documents from the United Nations or the Vatican.  German aviation forums have plenty of statements like

> Ja eine offizielle englische Übersetzung gibt es tatsächlich nicht
>
> *English: Um, yeah, actually there's no official English translation*

But the document's language is technical and precise enough that Google Translate can manage it accurately.

---

*Edit:* in 2020 Google Translate worked, but I've lost my copy of that translation, and in 2024 Google Translate generally translates only the easy parts and leaves technical words in the original German, even obvious ones like Ultraleichtflugzeug and Hängegleitern.  Worse, what it does translate is littered with gems such as

> The fact that the air transport vehicles are safe now that ultra-lightweight vehicles are being used
> means that they must be able to travel safely and that they must also be able to speak.

and

> The safety of the air transport is in the vicinity of the safety equipment and the safety shield is
> visible, with the maximum safety guarantee for the safety of the safety equipment.

Comment: "English: Yes, there is actually no official English translation" which is actually confusing and sounds like a machine translation. "English: _No_, there is actually no official English translation" would be a much more natural English wording. And far less self-contradictory.